# Foreign Key constraint conflict is not working in Sqlite (android studio)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Foreign Key constraint conflict is not working. When I insert invalid data into table it is  accepting. Foreign key constraint should prevent entering  invalid data into table.

```
public class DBClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private  static  final String dname= "NutritionDatabase";
    private static final int version =4;


    public DBClass(Context context){

        super(context, dname,null, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db){
        super.onOpen(db);
        db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            String gender_cat = "CREATE TABLE  gender_group" +
                    "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                    "name VARCHAR )";
            db.execSQL(gender_cat);

            String foodtbl = "CREATE TABLE Foods" +
                    "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                    "age VARCHAR ," +
                    "gender_cat INTEGER," +
                    "Food VARCHAR," +
                    "FOREIGN KEY (gender_cat) REFERENCES gender_group(id))";
            db.execSQL(foodtbl);

 }
        catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you carefully read over https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html and done what it says to do to turn on foreign key enforcement each time you connect to a database?

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute this after connecting/opening the database:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON
```

Next I suggest to make gender_cat `NOT NULL` in your create table statement, so the value is enforced. You can't insert anything without a value for `gender_cat`.

```
CREATE TABLE Foods(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    age VARCHAR ,
    gender_cat INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Food VARCHAR,
    FOREIGN KEY (gender_cat) REFERENCES gender_group(id))
```

Does this help?

And, please allow me, to suggest to either write your statement fully uppercase or all column names fully lower case. 
In your example you have `age` in lower but `Food` with an uppercase F.
Try to write structured, with a clear strategy and keep it through your design.
Same is true for your tables... `Foods` vs `gender_group`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your issue is that you are using `db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);` too late and thus Foreign Key support is not on when you insert the rows in the **onCreate** method.

That is the order is :-

1. onConfigure
2. onCreate
3. onOpen

i.e. when you insert the rows, as Foreign Key support hasn't been turned on the foriegn key constraint conflict doesn't happen and the rouge row is inserted.

As such you need to call **setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true)** in onConfigure for Foreign Key Support to be available in onCreate.

e.g. add the following to your DBClass

```
@Override
public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
    super.onConfigure(db);
}
```

The log will then contain (trapped not a crash) :-

```
2019-10-08 08:53:58.788 E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting gender_cat=30 age=1 Food=Foods Data(I just remove it
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
```

Comment: Thank you so much .. it is working.. Please one more . How can i write inner join query to retrieve data from both these tables.

Comment: @kinzaAkbar, if the answer helped then please tick it as answered. Re JOINS here's two basics selects that join the tables from each perspective `SELECT * FROM Foods JOIN gender_group ON gender_cat = gender_group.id;` and 
`SELECT * FROM gender_group JOIN Foods ON gender_cat = gender_group.id;` (note that as **id** is an ambiguous (i.e. which id) that table.column is used to eliminate the ambiguity as far as the join is concerned).